# Permission denied when running sh file

Tags: bash, permissions, java, minecraft, sh

I am trying to use an sh file to easily start a screen with my minecraft server console. I named this file mc.sh. I have another sh file in the same directory as mc.sh that runs fine.

Here is what is in mc.sh:

```
screen -S minecraft java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar spigot.jar nogui
```

Here is what is in the other sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh    
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar spigot.jar
```

The error message i get is `-bash: ./mc.sh: Permission denied`. The permissions for `mc.sh` are `-rw-rw-r-- 1`

Comment: Put 4 spaces in front of the line of code and it will format correctly even with a # ;) Please also show the permissions of "mc.sh" (`ls -l mc.sh` from the directory).

Comment: You could start by adding the error message you get, and also the output of "ls -l *.sh" in the directory you have the shell scripts. (30 seconds late!)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The permissions don't have the execute bit set, so bash won't execute the script. You can set the bit and execute the script:

```
chmod u+x mc.sh
./mc.sh
```

or let bash execute it for you:

```
bash mc.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can open the terminal (press Ctrl + Alt + T) and cd to the target directory:**

**cd /path_to_target**

To give the file "your_file_name" permission to execute:

**chmod +x your_file_name**